# How to permanently remove `import { cy } from "date-fns/locale"` so it stops erroring out cypress tests?

Tags: cypress

**UPDATE:**
This error comes from the auto import of `cy` from the date-fns library, which also has a `cy` of it's own. I've just commented it out in my code, since I don't necessarily want to get rid of auto-importing.

For some reason, every now and then I will get an error in my cypress tests `_locale.cy.visit is not a function`.
I've read some past posts on this and people say that removing the `import { cy } from "date-fns/locale"` will also remove the error. However, when I edit the test, it will be auto-imported and the error will happen again every now and then.

Is there anyway to remove this permanently or a better work around then constantly removing it?|

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the trick is to ensure VSCode already knows about the Cypress version of `cy`.

In my `tsconfig.json` I have a `"types": ["cypress"]` configuration

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Not sure if that is the key to your problem. Please reload VSCode after making the change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you disable the auto-import from your VS Code. To do that go to `File > Preferences > Settings` or `Code > Preferences > Settings` and write:

```js
//For js
"javascript.suggest.autoImports": false

//For TS
"typescript.suggest.autoImports": false
```

Comment: Thanks again for the comment!
I'm sure how to find this section on VS code, but I'll keep looking!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use typescript you can configure it via `jsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress"]
  }
  ...
}
```